# Unbound DNS sever does not log anything when I make a query

Tags: dns, logging

I have recently started using unbound dns.

I have configured all the things I need properly. But the server doesn't log when  I make a query.

I have no errors in the unbound.conf file

The following is my .conf file

```
# The server clause sets the main parameters.
server:
# whitespace is not necessary, but looks cleaner.

# verbosity number, 0 is least verbose. 1 is default.
verbosity: 1

# print statistics to the log (for every thread) every N seconds.
# Set to "" or 0 to disable. Default is disabled.
statistics-interval: 5


interface: 192.168.116.134

# port to answer queries from
port: 53


cache-min-ttl: 400
cache-max-ttl: 86400


# Enable IPv4, "yes" or "no".
do-ip4: yes

# Enable IPv6, "yes" or "no".
# do-ip6: yes

# Enable UDP, "yes" or "no".
    do-udp: yes

# Enable TCP, "yes" or "no".
    do-tcp: yes



access-control: 0.0.0.0/0 allow

# chroot: "/etc/unbound"


# username: "unbound"


# directory: "/etc/unbound"

# the log file, "" means log to stderr.
# Use of this option sets use-syslog to "no".
logfile: "/var/log/unbound/unbound.log"

forward-zone:
name: "."
forward-addr: 8.8.4.4
forward-addr: 8.8.8.8
```

The lig file does exist in the given directory and I have made the unbound user its owner using `chown`, but when I make a query the log file is still empty.

Platform: Ubuntu 18 Desktop

Answer (score 9):

The Unbound Debian/Ubuntu/similar package logs to `/var/log/syslog` by default. After some trial and error I figured out how to change it.

**Step 1**

Make sure all CHROOT directives are commented out and log directive added:

Search for the directive:

```
sudo grep -R "chroot" /etc/unbound/*
```

Note: We are searching entire config area. Your configuration file location may vary. I keep mine under `/etc/unbound/unbound.conf.d/99-custom-(servername).conf`.

At any rate, you should see something like this if commented out correctly:

```
# chroot:""
```

Also make sure you have these entries in your config file:

```
 use-syslog: no
 logfile: "/var/log/unbound/unbound.log"
```

Note: You can save the log anywhere you like, but you will have to adjust paths/filenames if you follow the rest of this guide.

**Step 2**

Make sure to create the folder/file with proper owner (unbound) and privileges:

```
sudo mkdir /var/log/unbound && sudo chmod 755 /var/log/unbound
sudo touch /var/log/unbound/unbound.log
sudo chown unbound:unbound /var/log/unbound /var/log/unbound/unbound.log
```

After restarting the service, it was still not working for me (or you).

I noticed it was still logging to syslog after turning up verbosity to debug. I also noticed some kernel logging showing "apparmor" was logging "DENIED" for the unbound log location access:

```
sudo cat /var/log/syslog | grep DENIED
```

Example in syslog:

```
 Dec 30 16:41:48 ip-192-168-1-1 kernel: [ 1368.641789] audit: type=1400 audit(1577724108.624:29): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/unbound" name="/var/log/unbound/unbound.log" pid=2247 comm="unbound" requested_mask="ac" denied_mask="ac" fsuid=112 ouid=112
```

**Step 3**

To correct this, I added a **local** override to `apparmor.d` area:

```
sudo nano /etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.unbound
```

Add this single line to it:

```
/var/log/unbound/unbound.log rw,
```

(Yes, with a comma on the end.) Save.

**Step 4**

Reload apparmor entries for unbound:

```
sudo apparmor_parser -r /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.unbound
```

**Step 5**

Restart Unbound:

```
sudo systemctl restart unbound
```

Check log:

```
$ sudo tail -f /var/log/unbound/unbound.log
[1577725445] unbound[2721:0] info: start of service (unbound 1.6.7).
```

WORKS. If you notice, when syslog logs it, it uses a standard date format. But, Unbound custom logging/non-syslog uses [Unix/Epoch time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (seconds since 1970) by default. If you wish to have timestamps like syslog, add this to your unbound config and reload service:

```
log-time-ascii: yes
```

**Step 6**

Log rotation:

If you wish the Unbound log to be rotated with the [logrotate](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/logrotate.8.html) service (you should), add this bit to the file `/etc/logrotate.d/unbound`:

```
/var/log/unbound/*.log {
    weekly
    rotate 7
    missingok
    notifempty
    compress
    delaycompress
    sharedscripts
    create 644
    postrotate
        /usr/sbin/unbound-control log_reopen
    endscript
}
```

Restart it all:
`sudo systemctl restart logrotate.service unbound.service`

Keep on eye on logging for a week or two to make sure things are logging and rotating correctly.

---

My config:
[gist text](https://gist.github.com/bmatthewshea/d77ac796813d8213e958ddc9885c245b)

References:
https://nlnetlabs.nl/documentation/unbound/unbound.conf/
https://wiki.debian.org/AppArmor/Debug
https://gist.github.com/kometchtech/06fc3326c83338afd151

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks for this. An internet search brought me here, and these exact steps worked perfectly for me, running unbound on a Raspberry Pi running Debian.

Comment: +1. Thank you for complete and detailed steps. Solved my problem too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a proper verbosity level. `3` should be sufficient.

> ```
> verbosity: <number>
>           The verbosity number, level 0 means no verbosity,  only  errors.
>           Level  1  gives  operational information. Level 2 gives detailed
>           operational information. Level 3 gives query level  information,
>           output  per  query.   Level 4 gives algorithm level information.
>           Level 5 logs client identification for cache misses.  Default is
>           level  1.  The verbosity can also be increased from the command-
>           line, see unbound(8).
> ```

Comment: I have done this but the logfile still remains empty .

Answer (score 0):

You are running in a chroot environment (`/etc/unbound`), which means your log should actually be kept at `/etc/unbound/var/log/unbound/unbound.log`. Is this where you are looking for it?

Comment: Hey i have done this but this didnt work.

Comment: The chroot directive is commented out, so he wasn't running chroot.

Comment: chroot is enabled by default. If you want to disable chroot, you need to uncomment it and set `chroot: ""`

Answer (score 0):

This is same answer as @b. shea.  Just the steps automated with **ansible**.

```
- name: unbound logging
  ansible.builtin.file:
    path: /var/log/unbound
    state: directory
    owner: unbound
    group: unbound
  become: true

- name: unbound logging - file
  ansible.builtin.file:
    path: /var/log/unbound/unbound.log
    state: touch
    owner: unbound
    group: unbound
  become: true

- name: unbound logging - apparmor
  ansible.builtin.copy:
    dest: /etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.unbound
    content: |
      /var/log/unbound/unbound.log rw,
  register: unbound_apparmor
  become: true

- name: unbound logging - apparmor parse
  ansible.builtin.shell:
    cmd: apparmor_parser -r /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.unbound
  become: true
  when: unbound_apparmor.changed
```